# Detect that client has closed connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cancellation-token

I have several different types if client connected to my web api.
Some of these have strictly internal policies regarding timeouts. For example a client I have well drop a connection if my api does not answer in less than 3 seconds.

In some cases my api need to grab information from a third party source and it can take longer than 5 seconds.

I am implementing a timeout reversal scenario so a client can call if he need to drop the connection for timeouts.

Is there any way to catch a connection dropped event in asp.net web api?

Comment: HTTP is stateless so I don't think it's possible. It depends on the external source but is there away to split the request into multiple and run them async side-by-side? It might improve performance if It's doing less heavy lifting in one request. It's just a stab in the dark.

Comment: Unfortunately that it's not possible. The average Of the requests duration is around 700ms but not in this case where some Times the third party service take more than 15 seconds

Comment: This all about `Network` between `client` and your `web API` also your `Web API` to where it should fetch the data according to the client request. Now once the client triggered the request to API. I guess there is no other options to stop it until the API respond to the client request. Unless you have to do some stuff to your web API just to limit the respond time. It's all depend on the target machine regarding the speed and its capabilities.

Comment: The asp.net web api is REST based, its stateless, it doesn't have the richer features of SOAP/WCF that you're after. Its not how the HTTP protocol works and in terms of TCP there isn't even a connection status and is why TCP keepalive is a controversial feature and is always off by default.

Comment: Thanks everybody for contributions. As I've written in the question, we are implementing a Timeout reversal feature in our API so we can instruct our clients to call a `cancel` api if in their environment they have got a timeout. This will for sure help us to handle those situations, at least in terms of api usage documentation. I was only guessing if I can use, for example, `IsClientConnected` or a form of `CancellationToken` as described in [this post](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/) related to AspNetCore.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a stab at this because I was having the same issue and the following worked for me:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
{
    return;
}
```

Again this worked in my case but I hope it helps you.

Here's Microsoft documentation:
[HttpResponse.IsClientConnected Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected?view=netframework-4.8)